# How can I using Pulumi get continuous deployment between ACR and AppService container?

Tags: pulumi

I want to create a Pulumi script that automatically creates an instance of an App-Service and tie it with a newly created Azure Container Registry. The goal is to get an automatic update of my AppService when i push a new image to the registry.

So what I think I need a way to get the **AppService - Container Settings -> Continuous Deployment -> WebHook URL** after I create the AppService using Pulumi.

From that URL I can then (i hope) create a containerservice RegistryWebhook between the registry and the app-service.

Or are there any simper way to achieve this? (Get a auto-update of an AppService after docker push?)

Comment: Do you want to push to docker using `docker push` or do you want to use `pulumi up` to do what you want?